# java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range(1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

Tags: java, mysql, csv, sql-insert

I have crated a java jframe program that allows you to input a csv file and then upload it to a local database however I am having trouble inserting all the data into the database. Any ideas on where I may be going wrong?

```
 try{
  BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename1));
  String line;

  while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
  String[]value=line.split(",");//Seperator
```

filename1 is the selected csv file from a jFilechooser.

```
   String sql="insert into websitehistory (Date, URL, VisitCount) "
      + "values (?,?,?)";


  pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  pst.setString(1, value[0]);
  pst.setString(2, value[1]);
  pst.setString(3, value[2]);
```

Here is mysql query of inserting the separated values into the database

This is my table structure:

```
Date           Varchar(244)
URL            VarChar(244)
VisitCount     VarChar(244)
```

And the type of data I would like to insert is:

```
31/01/2014  15:26:00,  https://www.youtube.com/,  13
31/01/2014  15:25:00,  https://www.youtube.com/,  17
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Check parameters that you add to your prepared statement.

Comment: You probably want to use `?` instead of each `'"+value[i]+"'` in your sql query. This way you can later replace `?` with correct value using `setXXX(number,value)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this query

```
String sql="insert into websitehistory (Date, URL, VisitCount) "
      + "values (?, ?, ?)";
```

Comment: changed it to:

String sql="insert into websitehistory (Date, URL, VisitCount) "
          + "values ( ?, ?, ? )";


but getting the error "check the right syntax to use near '?,?,?)' at line 1. Could it be the data inserted or the format of my database?

Comment: It may be useful to provide your table structure and the data your are trying to insert. Please edit your question and add these information.

Answer (score 1):

You should have place holders to use with Prepared Statement but not values directly dumped.

This is wrong:

```
String sql="insert into websitehistory (Date, URL, VisitCount) "
          + "values ('"+value[0]+"','"+value[1]+"','"+value[2]+"')";
```

Change it to:

```
String sql="insert into websitehistory (Date, URL, VisitCount) "
          + "values ( ?, ?, ? )";
```